# Why does a FIFO array queue lock not seem fair?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

In §7.5.1 of *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming* by Herlihy et al. (2nd ed., 2020), the authors present a simple lock that uses an array queue to achieve FIFO locking. Intuitively, the *n*th thread has a (thread-local) index into an array, and then spins on that array element until the *n - 1* thread unlocks the lock. Its code looks like this:

```java
public class ALock {
    ThreadLocal<Integer> mySlotIndex = new ThreadLocal<>() {
        @Override protected Integer initialValue() { return 0; }
    };
    AtomicInteger tail;
    volatile boolean[] flag;
    int size;

    public ALock(int capacity) {
        size = capacity;
        tail = new AtomicInteger(0);
        flag = new boolean[capacity];
        flag[0] = true;
    }

    public void lock() {
        int slot = tail.getAndIncrement() % size;
        mySlotIndex.set(slot);
        while (!flag[slot]) {};
    }

    public void unlock() {
        int slot = mySlotIndex.get();
        flag[slot] = false;
        flag[(slot + 1) % size] = true;
    }
}
```

I am using a minimal test program to check that this lock is fair. In a nutshell, I create `NUM_THREADS` threads and map each one to an array index `id`. Each thread tries to acquire the same lock. Once it succeeds, it increments a global `COUNT` and also increments `RUNS_PER_THREAD[id]`.

If the lock is correct, the final value of `COUNT` should equal the sum of the values in `RUNS_PER_THREAD`. If the lock is fair, the elements of `RUNS_PER_THREAD` should be approximately equal.

```java
public class Main {
    static long COUNT = 0;
    static int NUM_THREADS = 16;
//    static Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock(true);
    static ALock LOCK = new ALock(NUM_THREADS);
    static long[] RUNS_PER_THREAD = new long[NUM_THREADS];
    static Map<Long, Integer> THREAD_IDS = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var threads = IntStream.range(0, NUM_THREADS).mapToObj(Main::makeWorker).toArray(Thread[]::new);
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) THREAD_IDS.put(threads[i].getId(), i);
        for (var thread: threads) thread.start();
        try { Thread.sleep(300L); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        for (var thread: threads) thread.interrupt();
        try { Thread.sleep(100L); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) System.out.printf("Thread %d:\t%12d%n", i, RUNS_PER_THREAD[i]);
        System.out.println("Counted up to: \t\t\t" + COUNT);
        System.out.println("Sum for all threads: \t" + Arrays.stream(RUNS_PER_THREAD).sum());
    }

    private static Thread makeWorker(int i) {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) return;
                LOCK.lock();
                try {
                    COUNT++;
                    var id = THREAD_IDS.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    RUNS_PER_THREAD[id]++;
                } finally {
                    LOCK.unlock();
                }}});
    }
}
```

If the test program is run with a fair `ReentrantLock`, the final count of runs per thread with 16 threads (on my M1 Max Mac with Java 17) is almost exactly equal. If the same test is run with `ALock`, the first few threads seem to acquire the lock approximately 10 times more frequently than the last few threads.

Is `ALock`, as presented, unfair, and if so, why? Alternatively, is my minimal test flawed, and if so, why does it seem to demonstrate the fairness of `ReentrantLock`?

Comment: FYI, Your array of flags is _not_ `volatile`. There are no volatile arrays in Java. There are no volatile objects. The only thing that can be volatile is a _variable_ (including member variables, which some people call _fields._)  `volatile boolean flag[]` means that if one thread in your code executes `flag=...;` then that assignment is guaranteed to promptly become visible to other threads. But, if a thread assigns a _member_ of the array, `flag[i]=...`, as opposed to assigning the array variable itself, then the `volatile` guarantee does not apply.

Comment: Nothing in this example assigns another value to `flag`. The textbook authors (whose verbatim code this is) state that the `volatile` is to prevent the compiler from optimizing accesses. This is verbatim textbook code that is presented by the authors as correct code, not pseudocode.

Comment: Interesting. Which edition were you reading? `flag` is not `volatile` in the first edition. I would have said that the `volatile` keyword is meaningless because `flag` is never assigned. I tried reading what the _JLS, Java SE 17 Edition_ has to say about `volatile`, but in the limited time I have to spend, I could not decide how it answers either question A, Does the JLS permit the optimization that you are worried about if you take `volatile` out of your example? Or, question B, Does the JLS forbid the optimization if you leave it in?

Comment: Second edition (2020). I suspect that the main concern was that `while (!flag[slot]) {}` would turn into `while (true) {}`, but I haven't actually been able to produce a deadlock this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your test code has non-threadsafe update for `COUNT++`. Switch to `COUNT.incrementAndGet()` and:

```
static AtomicLong COUNT = new AtomicLong();
```

`ALock` will give unfair results especially when number of threads exceeds CPUs. The implementation relies on high CPU spin loop `while (!flag[slot])` and not all threads are having same opportunity to enter their lock spin-loops - the first few threads are performing more of the `lock-unlock` cycles. Adding `Thread.yield` should balance out the thread access to the boolean array so all threads have similar opportunities to run through their own lock spin loop.

```
while (!flag[slot]) {
   Thread.yield();
}
```

You should see different results if you try setting `NUM_THREADS` to be same or less than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` - the use of `Thread.yield()` may not make a difference compared to when `NUM_THREADS > Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

Using this lock class will lead to slower throughput as at any one time up to `N-1` threads are in high CPU spin loop waiting for the current locking thread to call `unlock()`. In ideal lock implementations, `N-1` waiters won't be consuming CPU.

The `ALock` locking stategy will only work if the exact same number of threads is used as provided `new ALock(NUM_THREADS)` because otherwise the use of `int slot = tail.getAndIncrement() % size;` may result in 2 threads reading from the same `slot`.

Note that any code relying on spin loop or `Thread.yield()` to work is not an effective implementation and should not be used in production code. Both can be avoided with the classes of `java.util.concurrent.*`.

Comment: What is the mechanism by which "one thread may appear to be favored over others"? I can see the difference in behavior with `Thread.yield()`, but it's not clear how it's achieved since threads can only acquire and release the lock in sequence.

Comment: The threads 0/1/2 are running lock/unlock many times before 3+ are even started causing an inbalance you've observed. Also contributing to this issue is if NUM_THREAD is much bigger than CPU cores - those early threads are hogging cpu and so adding `Thread.yield()` is giving another thread an opportunity to run.

Comment: You have edited your answer to provide more detail, but your answer only makes my original question more salient. If you claim the lock is literally *erroneous*, I should be writing to the textbook authors to tell them they have no business writing textbooks about locks. If each thread can only acquire the lock after the preceding thread has released it, it's not clear how it can release and reacquire the same lock immediately. After a thread tries to acquire the lock, it should spin, rather than try to reacquire the lock multiple times. If you think that's happening, I'd like to know how.

Comment: The code `while (!flag[slot]) {}` is not going to behave nicely with other thread. It's like revving a car to maximum when not in gear, or leaving a light on in a room no one is in. You can do it, but it is wasting a resource unnecessarily - in this case, CPU cycles that could be used by other threads.

Comment: This is a basic spinlock. That's what spinning *is*.

Comment: Your test code appears to work fine. `ALock` does not - it gives unfair results when number of threads exceeds CPUs. Using spin lock is not effective programming.